# How do I prevent React from unloading the content of the previous tab in Semantic UI React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

Say I have this in my app:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'Tab 1', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 1 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 2', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 2 Content</Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'Tab 3', render: () => <Tab.Pane>Tab 3 Content</Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleBasic = () => (
  <Tab panes={panes} />
)

export default TabExampleBasic
```

Whenever the tab is switched, it's being reloaded from scratch and I am losing all the changes inside the tab that I switched from if I return to it.

What is causing this and how I can keep the changed contents of tabs I switch from?

Tab docs: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-basic

Comment: what is being lost? do your panes have local state?

Comment: @azium my form data that is created using react-redux. No local state.

Comment: if the form data is in redux how can you lose it? should be filling the form fields from redux when you switch tabs, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state is lost because `render` function is called on each switch of `Tab` and it produces new objects. It was originally done for performance tasks. However, if you will use Redux or similar, you won't have this problem.

`0.72.0` introduced `renderActiveOnly` prop, there are examples of usage: [simple](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-basic-all) and [shorthand](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-pane-shorthand). You can set it to `false` and all tabs will be rendered.

Comment: Thanks but I am using redux-form and the form data are lost despite of that. Any idea?

Comment: `0.72.0` was released, I've updated answer. Now there is a simple solution for your case